# Swapping image on canvas eats memory

Tags: javascript, image, caching, canvas, memory-leaks

I think I have a problem related to:
[Systematically updating src of IMG. Memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682271/systematically-updating-src-of-img-memory-leak/34085389#34085389)

I don't have enough rep to comment on answers but https://stackoverflow.com/a/34085389/3270244 is exactly my case.

```
var canvasElement = $('canvas', camContainer);
var ctx = canvasElement[0].getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  image.src = '';
};

//for every getCamImg I receive exactly 1 image
socket.on('getCamImg', function(err, data) {
  if(data) {
    var dataImg = data.substring(data.indexOf(';') + 1);
    image.src = dataImg;
  }
  socket.emit('getCamImg');
});
socket.emit('getCamImg');
```

I change `img.src` every 1/10s (jpegs from a camera) and I can watch the browsers consume more and more memory. Firefox stops at 500MB, Edge stops at 100MB and for Chrome I stopped testing near 1G. If I remove the `img.src` change everything runs smooth (without an image of course).

I found a lot of (at leat I think so) related issues:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36142
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=337425
- [memory leak while drawing many new images to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850975/memory-leak-while-drawing-many-new-images-to-canvas#comment37477851_21122668)
- [Memory leaks when manipulating images in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309760/memory-leaks-when-manipulating-images-in-chrome?rq=1)

Somewhere someone mentioned (sorry for this :D) that maybe the cache is spammed because the old images are kept. I don't think it's a gc problem, because chrome has a tool to run him and nothing changes.

**Can someone reproduce this or guide me the correct way?**

*Update:*

```
  socket.on('getCamImg', function(err, data) {
    if(data) {
      var image = document.createElement("img");
      image.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        socket.emit('getCamImg');
        image.src = '';
      };
      image.src = dataImg;
    }
  });
```

This works good in Firefox (the `image.src=''` is important). Chrome still leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing nearly the same as you do in my current project. As this is too much for a comment I just share my observations in an answer. This is how I do it:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),

    onNewImgData = function (data) {
        //create a new image element for every base64 src
        var img = document.createElement("img");

        //bind the onload event handler to the image
        img.onload = function () {
            //draw the image on the canvas
            ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
            //do some stuff
            //...
            //done, request next image
        };

        //update the image source with given base64 data
        img.src = "data:image/bmp;base64," + data;
    };
```

I don't clean up anything and I can't see a memory leak in my application (no matter which browser). But I had a memory leak before, as I logged all the base64 data into the browser console :) That caused the exact same issue you've described.

Comment: Ok, just to be clear. You do this multiple times a second (the `img.src = ...` part)?
The idea with the console.log is good but I checked this first :D

Comment: Exactly. Everytime I receive new image data from my websocket I call the above function. This works with up to 20FPS in my current implementation. Without any leak.

Comment: Did you checked this in chrome? Sorry to be niggling but I can't see the fundamental difference :/

Comment: Something that comes to my mind: Do you `a)` actually request each image from your server when you are done displaying the current one or `b) `does your server just send images to your client, no matter if he's available for new rendering? I'm doing `a)` and I would recommend that ;)

Comment: Yes, it works in Chrome, Edge and FF. Chrome is my main browser and there RAM usage rarely goes near 100MB when using the above code.

Comment: I did `b`, but you are right! Thanks for this. Don't know why I did it the other way. But this doesn't solve the problem

mh .. ok so I need to investigate further... I need a break from this. I give it a new try tomorrow and give feedback!

Comment: Ok, good luck man :) Maybe you can create a Fiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: how to use this function? kinda lost here:D